# How to enable content security policy for identity server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, content-security-policy

I have a micro front-end which is connected to my identity server. In order for a user to access the micro front-end, the user needs to be authenticated via this ID server. The micro  front-end needs to be embedded in an iframe in my main application but since this micro front-end requires the ID server, I am getting an error on the console. Everything works fine before embedding this micro front-end but I get this problem as soon it gets into the iframe.

```
Refused to frame 'https://localhost:44300/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

I tried including this in my identity server's web.config file which resulted to the above error on the console.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors ''" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

It seems ID server does not allow its content to be embedded in an iframe. This perhaps might not be a good practice but per my requirements, i will like to know how to enable this.

**UPDATE**

Here is where the csp is defined

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            var result = context.Result;
            if (result is ViewResult)
            {
                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
                if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Content-Type-Options"))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
                }

                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
                if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Frame-Options"))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
                }

                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy
                var csp = "default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self';";
                // also consider adding upgrade-insecure-requests once you have HTTPS in place for production
                //csp += "upgrade-insecure-requests;";
                // also an example if you need client images to be displayed from twitter
                // csp += "img-src 'self' https://pbs.twimg.com;";

                // once for standards compliant browsers
                if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Content-Security-Policy"))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", csp);
                }
                // and once again for IE
                if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Content-Security-Policy"))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Security-Policy", csp);
                }

                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy
                var referrer_policy = "no-referrer";
                if (!context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Referrer-Policy"))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", referrer_policy);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is really a bad idea to try to iframe IdentityServer, because then its hard for the user to know where he is actually logging in to.

If you still want to change it you need to look at the **SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs** file in the **QuickStart** folder, that one defines the CSP.

In this file you can tweak the security headers that are sent to the browser. You need to look at the CSP and the X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What can I change in this file in order to be able to load the page in the iframe? I  am developing a modular UI and the underlying framework uses an iframe to embed all other applications. Is just a prototype I am working on so I will change that later maybe to another framework. I updated my question with csp file content.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope you can accept this answer.

Comment: i removed the frame-ancestors directive and and it now works. Thanks for your answer